# Retrieve data from database using sms through mobile(text) in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mobile

I want to retrieve data from database using mysql in codeigniter/custom php through text from my mobile.
I am student and new developer.

Comment: We can understand and probably help you with your problem better if we know what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: for instance i want to know my result on my university's webiste i just send my roll number as a text massage from my phone and get result from university's website.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to point you in the right direction although a little research would take you there anyway. You should start by looking for an SMS API in `php`. A [simple google search](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20sms%20api) returns a lot of relevant results.

[TextMagic](https://code.google.com/p/textmagic-sms-api-php/) is one such SMS Api and is hosted on https://code.google.com/. It is pretty well documented and quite simple to use:

```
$api = new TextMagicAPI(array(
    "username" => "your_user_name",
   "password" => "your_API_password", 
));

 $text = "Hello world!";
 $phones = array(9991234567);
 $is_unicode = true;

 $api->send($text, $phones, $is_unicode);
```

So it's just about creating an account and it allows you to receive SMS as well.It all depends on how you want to go about it (if you are looking for a free or paid service and other features that you might want).

Anyway, I hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: for instance i want to know my result on my university's webiste i just send my roll number  as a text massage from my phone and get result from university's website.

Comment: It is still quite vague what you're asking because you don't have any code posted and it's impossible to just assume how the results are stored and displayed on your website. You should start by trying to make a simple script in `php` that does this for you and run it in the browser first. The `SMS` integration can be done later on.